# Apply shipping charges only below a certain threshold with OpenCart

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I am making a ecommerce website using OpenCart; I want the customer to get free shipping above 250 rupees only. How can I do it?

Comment: `if($price<250){ $price = $price+250;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Free Shipping method has a setting called **Total** which allows you to do this.

Log in to your admin panel and if it's not already installed click **Install** next to **Free Shipping** in **Admin > Extensions > Shipping** (https://example.com/admin/index.php?route=extension/shipping/install&extension=free)

Then click **Edit** or navigate to: http://example.com/admin/index.php?route=shipping/free and set the first field called **Total** to 250. This will enabled the **Free Shipping** extension above 250.

If you *also* want to disable whatever other shipping extension you're using below 250 you'll need to modify `catalog/model/shipping/your-shipping-method.php`. The code required and exact placement depends entirely on which method you happen to be using, but it would probably look something like this:

```
if ($this->cart->getSubTotal() >= 250) {
    $status = false;
}
```